# How do you add a C++/WinRT Button Click handler?

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

How does one translate the Microsoft [ButtonBase.Click Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click) information for C++/WinRT into a prototype declaration and definition?

In Visual Studio Community 2017, version 15.9.5, I created a standard project, viz., Blank App (C++/WinRT), which has a button (myButton) as part of it.  I want to learn how to add a second button.  I have added the XAML code for a second button (myButton2), but thereafter I am stuck.

```
<Page
    x:Class="X003.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:X003"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPan" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="LightBlue">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
        <Button x:Name="myButton2" Click="ClickHandler2">Click Me2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I could just copy the code from the first button that the Blank App (C++/WinRT) provided.  But, if I did not have the first button as an example, I would not know how I would translate the Microsoft documentation, viz.,

```
// Register
event_token Click(RoutedEventHandler const& handler) const;

// Revoke with event_token
void Click(event_token const& cookie) const;

// Revoke with event_revoker
Click_revoker Click(auto_revoke_t, RoutedEventHandler const& handler) const;
```

into a Click handler.  The first line of the Microsoft documentation, viz.,

```
event_token Click(RoutedEventHandler const& handler) const;
```

is, I take it, the format to be used in creating the handler.  It does not look like the handler already in the project, viz.,

```
void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
```

I thought that it could be added to the .idl file.  But, the .idl file does not have the first button in it.

The example code with Microsoft provides is for C#, even when "C++/WinRT" is selected at the top-right of the page.

The new version of C++/WinRT has a lot of documentation, almost too much.  Coming from having used C#/WPF/XAML, I cannot see my way clearly to doing similar work with C++/WinRT.

Finally, the project Properties tab is of no help.  In C# the events were listed and choosing one would result in a declaration and basic definition being created in the code.  For C++/WinRT, when the cursor is on the control in the XAML page, the events section of the Properties page shows the name of the control, myButton or myButton2, and indicates "The document item has no code-behind file.  Add a code-behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers."  But, there is no code-behind file for the existing button, myButton.

Comment: This question was linked to in a Microsoft thread here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does one translate the Microsoft ButtonBase.Click Event information for C++/WinRT into a prototype declaration and definition?

Not sure what do you mean by `prototype declaration and definition` since given information itself is prototype.

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/handle-events) page you can find more information about event handling in C++/Winrt. Link explains about handling and revoking events with delegates and gives example of Button click event handling for `C++/WinRT`. In short you need to have handler and register it through delegate.

```
// function that handles event
void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const& /* sender */, RoutedEventArgs const& /* args */)
{
    Button().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
}
...
// register above function for event handler
Button().Click({ this, &MainPage::ClickHandler });
```

**UPD:** I tried to check regarding error `The document item has no code-behind file. Add a code-behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers` when user tries to access Properties and Event Handlers. I could easily reproduce this issue by creating Blank App (C++/Winrt) after installing [cppwinrt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) extension.

I checked [photo editor sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-editor) from ms github to further down debug this problem. In this sample app I failed to load XAML design mode. First it requested me to update my Windows version to 1809, but I failed to update. So I decided to rollback to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-editor/commit/3fd2defc5cdb46a740db4aad99b1b7f7c19be623) commit id which does not require Windows 1809 update.

After this XAML design failed with `Some assembly references are missing. Building to restore the NuGet cache might resolve this issue.` error. Research lead me to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/279) which is closed with following comment

> This is currently unsupported. The XAML team is currently working on designer support, so you should see this light up in a future update to the Windows SDK.

After opening [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1398) in MS docs github, I got following response from them and according [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#blank-app-cwinrt) of MS docs was updated.

> I've added the following info to the "Blank App (C++/WinRT)" subsection of this topic, since that's the project template that uses XAML as its UI.
>
> "Visual Studio's XAML design surface support for C++/WinRT is close to parity with C#. One exception is the Events tab of the Properties window. With a C# project, you can use that tab to add event handlers; with a C++/WinRT project, that facility is not present. But see Handle events by using delegates in C++/WinRT for info on how to add event handlers to your code."
>
> This change should be live soon. Please let me know if there's anything further I can add.

Comment: miradham, I added the registration for a second button to the constructor for MainPage, based on the reference you cited.  What I do not understand is that no such registration is in that constructor for the first button, the button which is part of the Blank App.  Three questions: 1. Why is the registration event for the first button not present in the Microsoft generated code?  2. Can the 2nd button's registration be removed after one compilation? 3. Why is the events section of the Properties tab for XAML controls blank?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user34299 regarding #1 You already have `Click="ClickHandler"` in xaml code. That's also one way to add event handler. #2 No it can't. Why would you do so? #3 Not sure regarding this yet, let me update my VS and check it.

Comment: @user34299 I created sample C++ Blank App(Universal Windows) and added a button. Click event in Properties page of the Button is empty. When double click on that, `Button_Click` event handler auto generated. As per your description it seems `.cpp` and `.h` files are not generated or deleted by accident in your case.

Comment: When I add a button, the way you describe, the events section of the Properties tab shows no events to double-click on.  Clicking on the lighting bold of the Properties tab shows the newly added button as a Button with its name, but no events, only the text where event listings should be, "The document item has no code-behind file. Add a code-behind file and a class definition before adding event handlers."

Comment: You were not using the same VS menu app as am I.  You are using C++ Blank App (**Universal Windows**), as you said.  I am using C++ Blank App (**C++/WinRT**), which is marked as "experimental" in the top-right description.  The app I am using is further down the menu from the one you are choosing after the C++/WinRT extension has been added to Visual Studio.

Comment: @user34299 please check my updated answer. It seems xaml design view is not yet supported for C++/WinRT.

Comment: Thank you for the complete reply.  In the past I had used MFC and C#/WPF for Windows applications.  In December, when I learned of the fully C++ 17 compliant SDK for Windows apps, I started looking into it.  That there was no XAML event support made me think I was doing something wrong.  Microsoft’s big C++/WinRT rollout was in May, 2018 and this problem was not mentioned, even though it was longstanding by then.

Comment: @user34299  I have reported this missing point in MS docs as github issue and got response from MS. Please see updated answer. Please feel free to comment further in the github issue if you think they need to add something more to the docs. If you think my answer  is useful, please don't forget to accept it (:

Comment: Where has stevewhims posted this topic which he says is live now?

Comment: @user34299 It is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt#blank-app-cwinrt)